# How do I find out where brew links end up?

Tags: macos, homebrew

`brew link` puts symlinks all over the place. How do I find out where, for a particular package?

For example, I have cairo installed via brew. `brew list cairo` shows me a list of installed files. When I link cairo, brew creates symlinks.

```
$ brew link cairo                                          
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.0... 28 symlinks created
```

How do I find out where those symlinks are?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

symlinks are *typically* in `/usr/local/` and is defined as by `brew --prefix`. To see where the app symlinks to (using `wget` as an example),

```
$ brew link wget --dry-run
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1
To relink: brew unlink wget && brew link wget
```

According to the `brew` man page:

```
If  --dry-run or -n is passed, Homebrew will list all files which would be linked or which would be deleted by brew link --overwrite, but will not actually link or delete any files.
```

To see where all of the files are located, use the `list [formula] --verbose` option like so

```
$ brew list wget --verbose
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1/AUTHORS
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1/bin/wget
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1/ChangeLog
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1/COPYING
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1/NEWS
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1/README
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1/share/info/wget.info
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.1/share/man/man1/wget.1
```

Comment: Worth noting that you have to unlink before linking with `--dry-run`, or brew will complain with "already linked."

Comment: If, like me, you hit this (apparent bug), you have to `unlink`; `unlink` also supports `--dry-run`, so it's then just a matter of whether you need to run `link` or `unlink` w/ that flag.

(I wish `link --dry-run` would just list, or `brew list` would just list…)

Answer (score 3):

In the case the package is already linked you can list existing links:

```
brew unlink <formulae> --dry-run
```

To get more info about the links:

```
brew unlink <formulae> --dry-run | xargs ls -l
```